# Beautifying raw weather results to something more readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap

I am creating a weather app using the `pyowm` module and I managed to get the temperature of *xyz* place but the thing is it is not so appealing to others because it's just raw results and I want to make it readable. Below is the code and its output.

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('myapikey')
observation = owm.weather_at_place('London,uk')
w = observation.get_weather()
result=w.get_temperature('celsius')
print (result)
#the output is {'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp': 19.64, 'temp_kf': None, 'temp_max': 21.8}
```

So now all I want is that it should be readable like,

```
place:London
temperature:17 degrees
maximum:21.8
minimum:17.0
```

I'm aware of regular expressions but I am not sure whether one can implement it in this as no matter how hard I try it gives me errors.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions - that's JSON, and Python has a built-in module for parsing it for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe are you sure it's JSON - looks like the library has done whatever and put it in a Python `dict`...

Comment: @JonClements oh, yes, then perhaps `ast.literal_eval`, but still not regex!

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need regex, regex is for detecting patterns in strings and whatnot. What you want is to construct a string out of data. There are many, many ways to accomplish this, but the easiest is probably

```
'\n'.join(key + ':' + str(v) for k, v in result.items())
```

If you want to use a different label for the values in your dictionary (say `maximum` instead of `temp_max`) than the keys given, you will have to define a second dictionary mapping the `results` keys to a new group of labels, and use `zip` or some other method of combining the two structures.

Comment: im sorry can you tell me how to implement this? thank you and sorry for bieng a noob

Comment: instead of passing `result` to `print()` directly, pass that line of code to `print()` like this: `print('\n'.join(key + ':' + str(v) for k, v in result.items()))`

Comment: I AM VERY THANKFUL TO YOU,i have but one last question,how do i put multiple statements bcoz when i put temeprature instead of key it just says temperature for all items and not max.temperature and minimum temprature.SORRY FOR BEING A PAIN IN THE A**.

Comment: i found an easy way to do this please take a look                    print(result['temp']) and what it does is finds the variable next to 'temp' so i think this might be 'the most easiest way"

Comment: yes, you are accessing a single entry in the dictionary, the one that corresponds to the key `temp`.